# Creating 3 Node Hadoop Cluster

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cluster-computing

I'm creating 3 Node Hadoop cluster on my Ubuntu 16 machine plus two AWS EC2 machines.

My local machine (Ubuntu 16) will be working as Name Node and two other AWS EC2 machines will be working as Data nodes.

I've few doubts.

1) Do I need to install, Hadoop on DataNodes (AWS EC2 machines) too, like I've installed on Name node ( My Local Machine)  .. ?

2) I'm able to communicate in between all my nodes in cluster (Name Node to Data Nodes and vice versa). In Name Node where I need to add Data nodes Public DNS in Name node machine so that my Name node could spread data acorss my two data nodes cluster ..?

Please share your inputs ..!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Hadoop namenode Version should be exact replica of all the datanodes.
   Then only cluster will work.
2. If you are using later version of hadoop- 3.0 then in *workers* file you have specify the datanode ip or DNS.

   OR
3. If you are using lower version of hadoop- 3.0 then in *slaves* file you have specify the datanode ip or DNS.